# select rows where column contains value from comma separated list

Tags: php, mysql, find-in-set

I searched for questions like this.. But I could not find answer to fetch data from mysql table.

I have mysql table like below :

```
| id   |    division  | branch
|  1   |    Mumbai    | Thane
|  2   |    Mumbai    | Kalyan
|  3   |    Pune      | Nagar
|  4   |    Pune      | Sangamner
|  5   |    Solapur   | Jat
|  6   |    Solapur   | Satara
```

Now I have a comma separated string as follows

```
$string = Mumbai,Solapur
```

I want to fetch rows where division column contains Mumbai and Solapur

I tried FIND_IN_SET() but it doesn't work.

e.g.

```
$query = "select * from table where FIND_IN_SET($string, division);
```

Comment: You need quotes around `$string`. But it would be better to use a prepared statement with parameters instead of substituting a variable into the SQL.

Comment: @Barmar Just Tried with quotes arounf $string but no luck...

Comment: I told you that it's best to use a prepared statement. Don't waste time adding quotes.

Comment: But I'm sure ```$query = "select * from table where FIND_IN_SET('$string', division)``` would work. I don't know why it didn't work for you.

Comment: @Barmar it works if only one value is there.... e.g. If only Mumbai is there, record fetched but if one than more value with comma, then not fetching...

Comment: You have the order of arguments wrong. It should be `FIND_IN_SET(division, '$string')`

Comment: Why not using a `IN` clause?

`select * from table where division in ('Mumbai','Solapur')`. Obviously you have to add some logic to dynamically create the query (string or prepared statement), but i think the clause you were looking for is this.